# Outlook VBA not updating follow up flag

Tags: vba, outlook

I am currently experiencing an issue where my Outlook VBA code is not updating the follow up flag on emails in my Outlook view. What is interesting is when I check the assignment it seems to be updating correctly. Below is my code for reference:

```
Sub RemoveDuplicateItems()
    Dim objFolder As Folder
    Dim objDictionary As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim strKey As String

    Set objDictionary = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    'Select a source folder
    Set objFolder = Outlook.Application.Session.PickFolder

    If Not (objFolder Is Nothing) Then
       For i = objFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
           Set objItem = objFolder.Items.Item(i)

           Select Case objFolder.DefaultItemType
                  'Check email subject, body and sent time
                  Case olMailItem
                       strKey = objItem.Subject
                       'MsgBox "Looking at: " + strKey + ", Flag is: " + objItem.FlagRequest
                       strKey = Replace(strKey, "RE: ", "")
                       strKey = Replace(strKey, "Re: ", "")
                       strKey = Replace(strKey, "FW: ", "")
           End Select

           'Remove the duplicate items
           If objDictionary.Exists(strKey) = True Then
              If objDictionary(strKey).SentOn <= objItem.SentOn Then
                   flagString = objDictionary(strKey).FlagRequest
                   objDictionary(strKey).Delete
                   objDictionary.Remove strKey
                   If flagString <> "Follow Up" And flagString <> "" Then
                        objItem.FlagRequest = flagString
                   End If
                   'MsgBox "Stored flag: " + objItem.FlagRequest
                   objDictionary.Add strKey, objItem

              Else
                    If objItem.FlagRequest <> "Follow Up" And objItem.FlagRequest <> "" Then
                        objDictionary(strKey).FlagRequest = objItem.FlagRequest
                    End If
                    objItem.Delete
              End If
           Else
              objDictionary.Add strKey, objItem
           End If
       Next i
    End If
    Set objMsg = Nothing
    Set objItem = Nothing
    Set objDictionary = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, I need to save the mail object:

objItem.FlagRequest = flagString
objItem.Save